# How do I prevent Sum indices from being "absorbed" by other sums?

Tags: summation

Consider the following test definition:

```
a[j_] = Sum[1/f[(i+j)^2], {i, 1, Infinity}]
```

Now, consider the following expressions:

```
In[2]= Sum[a[i], {i, 1, Infinity}] //. {f[x_] -> x^2}

Sum: Sum does not converge.
Out[2]= Sum[Pi^4/1440, {i, 1, Infinity}]
```

versus

```
In[3] = Sum[a[k], {k, 1, Infinity}] //. {f[x_] -> x^2}

Out[3] = Sum[PolyGamma[3,1+k], {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

Both examples yield different results and the only difference is the choice of the index name. My guess is, that in the first example, the index was absorbed by the inner `Sum` in `a[j_]`. How do I prevent this when I have to use many nested sums? I.e. how do I make them act only on their index even though another index might have the same name? I could of course use different names, but that might not be feasible if there are many sums generated from the same definition.

### Update

The two answers solve the problem already partially. However, consider the following example:

```
In[4]= a[k1]*a[k2]
Out[4]= (Sum[1/f[(i$1234+j)^2], {i$1234, 1, Infinity}]) * Sum[1/f[(i$1234+j)^2], {i$1234, 1, Infinity}]
```

Here, both `Sum`s will have the same index again. This can lead to problems if I want to merge the sums.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be really sure that there are no side effects due to variable reuse, you can make the iterator local using `Module`

```
Module[{i}, Sum[a[i], {i, 1, Infinity}] //. {f[x_] -> x^2}]

(* Sum[PolyGamma[3, 1 + i$10798]/6, {i$10798, 1, Infinity}] *)
```

Comment: I have made an update to my question, this is not a full solution to the problem in some cases.

Comment: @HerpDerpington Within a sum, Mathematica scopes the iterator variable to that sum environment, so that it is not influenced by outside definitions. In your updated expression, Mathematica by itself would therefore not pull one sum into the other, as there may be unwanted consequence. However, if you want to modify the sums by hand, you can make each iterator unique by wrapping every sum in ```Module``` and making the iterator local.

Answer (score 3):

Define `a` with local variables (that is, variable symbols for `a` will be only for the `a`, despite the same character was input in different session, such as nested list):

```
a[j_] := Module[{j0 = j, i}, Sum[1/f[(i + j0)^2], {i, 1, Infinity}]]
Sum[a[i], {i, 1, Infinity}] //. {f[x_] -> x^2}

(* Sum[PolyGamma[3, 1 + i]/6, {i, 1, Infinity}] *)
```

Comment: I have made an update to my question, this is not a full solution to the problem in some cases.

Comment: @HerpDerpington I stand with my answer; Please read the answer thoroughly.  Define `a` as shown in my answer and do `a[k1]*a[k2]`.

Comment: The colon was missing, thanks